# How to redirect to the home page from a template?

Tags: template, redirect

I am in catalog\product\compare\list.phtml and I want to redirect to the homepage, like this:

```
if($someThing) {
    // redirect to homepage
    $this->_redirect('home'); // --> doesnt work
    $this->_redirect(Mage::getBaseUrl()); // --> doesnt work
}
```

I tried several things, none worked so far. How do I do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: try  `$this->_redirect('/');`

Comment: keyul It Worked for me thanx a lot

Answer (score 11):

From a template you can simply use the following:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

I am interested as to why you are doing redirects directly in the template rather than at the controller level?

Comment: Agree. JavaScript might be another option, closer to a "view" solution. Still you might want to move this to a controller.

Answer (score 9):

As  `_redirect()` is `a controller class function` .By using thi`s you cannot direction at any pages from phtml page`. So you need to controller `object which will redirect to home page`

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl())
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
```

`exit` stop `execution of current page`

Answer (score 7):

You should never redirect to the homepage from a template.
Do that from the controller before any output is done.
You can use the code that DavidManners gave you, but do it before you call `renderLayout` in the controller.